# Quantidade de itens alinhados verticalmente de acordo com height da div

Tags: html, css, css3

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando fazer um layout basico semelhante a tela inicial do Windows 8/10, e em um container gostaria de alinhar itens verticais de 80x80, e se de acordo com o *Height* por acaso algum itens não couber nesta primeira coluna ser iniciado na segunda coluna, e assim sucessivamente como na imagem.

[image: Modelo]

Desculpe se eu não consegui expressar bem, obrigado.

Comment: A esperança estaria no flexbox, mas na vertical é um tanto inconsistente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao meu ver a opção de melhor sintaxe é utilizando flexbox

- `display:flex` Adicionando ao pai
- `flex-direction:column` Para crescer no formato de coluna com
- `flex-wrap:wrap;` Quando acabar o espaço da coluna de uma coluna, deve criar uma nova
- `align-content:flex-start`alinhando tudo para a esquerda para a direita com

```css
.pai{
  
  height:400px;
  width:800px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  
}



.pai .filha{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
    
}

.filha.pequeno{
  height:100px;
}

.filha.medio{
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filha pequeno"></div>
  <div class="filha medio"></div>
  <div class="filha pequeno"></div>
  
  <div class="filha medio"></div>
  <div class="filha pequeno"></div>
  <div class="filha pequeno"></div>
  <div class="filha pequeno"></div>
  
  <div class="filha medio"></div>
  <div class="filha pequeno"></div>
  <div class="filha medio"></div>
</div>
```

Dá pra fazer com `float` também mas prefiro esse, caso tenha 
outras dúvidas tem a  documentação nesse [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o Flexbox para isso, acho que o principal problema é a compatibilidade com os browsers mais antigos, pois estas funções vão funcionar somente no IE11+

Referências:

[Fonte e outro exemplo](https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/)

[Flex Wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp)

[Flex Direction](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp)

Segue um exemplo.

```css
.flex{
      display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#c1{height: 40px;  border: 1px solid green;}
#c2{height: 80px;  border: 1px solid green;}
#c3{height: 120px;  border: 1px solid green;}
#c4{height: 120px;  border: 1px solid green;}

.inner{width:36px; height:36px; background: blue;margin: 2px;color: white; font-weight: 700; text-align: center;}
```

```html
Div Container Padrão 1
<div id="c1" class="flex">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>  
</div>

Div Container Padrão 2 
<div id="c2" class="flex">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>  
</div>

Div Container Padrão 3
<div id="c3" class="flex">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>  
</div>

Div Container Padrão 4
<div id="c4" class="flex">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>  
  <div class="inner">4</div>
  <div class="inner">5</div>
  <div class="inner">6</div>
  <div class="inner">7</div>
  <div class="inner">8</div>
  <div class="inner">9</div>
</div>
```